# iPhone : friend list, how did Facebook accomplished that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I wonder if anyone can speculate or better yet provide a piece of code as for the implementation of the lengthy friends list in the Facebook iPhone app.

when you open the app and go strait to the friends list, you get the list almost in an instant, at least for me with ~500 friends.

when I try it in my own app it takes lots of precious seconds to populate the table view with the same data, so how does Facebook accomplished such a quick response time ?

upon looking at the tableview in the facebook app you notice there is no scroll bar usually found in such tableview, could that be one sign of the neat trick facebook is utilizing to achieve this rapid rows insert ? could it be they implemented some sort of a virtual tableview with only holds a few dozen rows but rotates them ?

any thoughts ?

Comment: sorry it took so long to get back to you. I worked till midnight last night. You have a code example now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the UITableView will let you do this. There are a number of examples on the internet with UITableView and Custom Cell's

Essentially, you load your images in the background, and you reuse the Cells that are in the tableview

**EDIT** Added example code to demonstrate how this is accomplished.
**IMPORTANT NOTE**
This code was not tested and may or may not actually function as is.
It was pasted with some editing for length. I did a lot more then this in my app, but in the interest of keeping with the example requested I omitted a lot.

**On with the example:**
Here is where I get the cell, load it with the items that are readily available. And send it to the background thread to load the rest.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OfferCell";
    static NSString *CellNib = @"OfferItem";

    OfferCell* cell = (OfferCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (OfferCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }



    NSDictionary* couponPackage = [self.jsonOfferData valueForKey:@"result"];

    NSArray *couponList = [couponPackage valueForKey:@"offers"];

    if ([couponList count] >= indexPath.row )
    {
        NSDictionary* couponData = [couponList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Coupon *coupon = [[Coupon alloc] initWithDictionary:couponData];

        NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:cell,@"cell",coupon,@"coupon", nil];

        //Right here you would try to load any cached imaged from disk.

        //Then send a Thread to the background to load the image.
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadTableViewCellData:) withObject:params];

        //Load up the rest of the custom info into the custom cell.
        [cell.captionLabel setText:coupon.name];
        [cell.subTextLabel setText:coupon.subText];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
        [cell setCommand:coupon.command];
        [cell setParameter:coupon.commandArgs];
        [cell setImageURL:coupon.imageURL];
        [cell setImageAltURL:coupon.imageAltURL];
        [cell setRegistrationCode:coupon.registrationCode];
        [coupon release];
    }    

    return cell;
}
```

as you can see, i call a background thread before i even load the custom content in the cell.

```
- (void) loadTableViewCellData:(NSDictionary*) objectData
{
    OfferCell *cell = [objectData objectForKey:@"cell"];
    Coupon *coupon = [objectData objectForKey:@"coupon"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[coupon iconURL]]]];
    [objectData setValue:image forKey:@"image"];
    self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImageOnMainThread:) withObject:objectData
}
```

after downloading the image, i send a Main thread request to update the Image that is in the cell object.

```
- (void) setImageOnMainThread:(NSDictionary*) objectData
{
    OfferCell *cell = [objectData objectForKey:@"cell"];
    Coupon *coupon = [objectData objectForKey:@"coupon"];
    UIImage *image = [objectData objectForKey:@"image"];
    cell.icon.image = image;
}
```

**##AGAIN This May not Actually Function. ##**
I did not copy all of my code for this. this is a hammer out so you can get the idea.
play with the code and test it. but the fundamentals are.

- Dequeue the cell that will fit your needs (Reuse Identifier)
- Use the cell if it can be dequeue'd or create a new one with a reuse identifier (my example uses a xib file named OfferItem.xib)
- Send a thread to the background that will load the image data from disk or url (a combination of both is recommended)
- Send a thread back to the UI when you are ready to load the image into the View (Updating the UI must be done on the main thread)

if you can do that, then your friends list (or in this case offers) will be loaded up as fast as possible. and the Images will pop on the screen as soon as they download.

Also if you use a Caching technique it will be faster for subsequent loads because in the the first method {tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:} you would load up the cached image immediately.

Aside from that, this should load your cell's pretty fast.

Comment: can you elaborate please, or maybe provide links to good tutorials ? do you think this is how the Facebook app does it ? or there is more to it ?

Comment: I will try this evening to add some example code or find a tutorial for you.

Answer (score 1):

They obviously load the data from a local resource (plist, ManagedObject, ...)

Have a look at some sample code to draw a TableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
return cell;
}
```

The dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: thing is one reason why TableViews in iOS can draw quickly. It works somehow like this:

1)You provide an identifier for a cell you're creating.

2)Cells that are visible at first get alloced (with identifier)

3)When a Cell is moved off the screen it gets put on a pile *MyCellIdentifier*

4)Whenever the system needs to draw a cell of identifier:*MyCellIdentifier* it first looks whether there are any cells currently unused on the *MyCellIdentifier* pile. If that's the case it picks one off the pile and thus doesn't have to alloc a new one. That way expensive allocing can be kept at a minimum.

I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: yes, this is what I believe we already do, but it is still considerably slower than what the Facebook app can do, it is the only app I saw that can display (or trick me to believe it does) hundreds of tableview lines very quickly. so I thought it may utilize some trick to do so and the lack of scrollbar was a hint...

Comment: The iPod app and many other apps all display a UITableView with hundreds of rows and do so very efficiently. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: facebook app displays complex rows with multiple text labels and images in each one, and hundreds of them. if you try to populate a tableview like that you get a waiting time in the seconds...

Comment: They don't display the images immediately, rather they have a grey placeholder and load the image when the cell becomes visible.